# YII2, подсчет COUNT по нескольким полям

Tags: yii2, count

Появилась необходимость собирать статистику.

Для этого скрипт должен ходить по таблице и подсчитывать количество различных статусов.

Пример статусов: (1, 2, 3, 4). (1 - в работе, 2-готов, 3- закрыт, 4-удален).

Для того чтобы не делать на каждый статус отдельный запрос и не мучать БД, решил все одним запросом сделать.

```
$query = TableName::find()->asArray()->select(['COUNT(*) AS status'])->where(['user' => 00034, 'status' => [1,2,3,4]])->groupBy('status')->all();
```

Данный запрос работает, но вот в чем проблема. Он не показывает у какого статуса сколько совпадений. Он просто показывает что нашел и в каком количестве.

```
 array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Вопрос. Как мне сделать чтобы он выводил на каждый статус количество совпадений, т.е. (ну или хотя бы можно было идентифицировать, какие статусы он посчитал)

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["1"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["2"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["3"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["4"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

Неразумным (с точки зрения количества запросов к БД) решением проблемы является следующее:

```
        $count[0] = TableName::find()->where(['user' => 00034, 'status' => '1'])->count();
        $count[1] = TableName::find()->where(['user' => 00034, 'status' => '2'])->count();
        $count[2] = TableName::find()->where(['user' => 00034, 'status' => '3'])->count();
        $count[3] = TableName::find()->where(['user' => 00034, 'status' => '4'])->count();
        $count[4] = TableName::find()->where(['user' => 00034, 'status' => '5'])->count();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы в select выбираете только COUNT, поэтому и показывается только сколько совпадений нашлось. Попробуйте так:

```
$query = TableName::find()->asArray()->select(['status', 'COUNT(*) AS count'])->where(['user' => 00034, 'status' => [1,2,3,4]])->groupBy('status')->all();
```

Comment: Да, это работает. Спасибо. Так хотя бы появилась возможность идентифицировать, какой статус был подсчитан. Видимо нужно лучше изучить возможности select.